# os-prober in Arch don't find Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux

I'm trying to do a dual boot in Arch, I install Arch how is recommended in the official guide but when I run `os-prober` don't find Ubuntu. The partition where is EFI "Ubuntu" is the same partition for EFI "Arch".

[image]

[image]

But `os-prober` in Ubuntu works and Find Arch without problems.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Detecting other operating systems](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Detecting_other_operating_systems)

> To have `grub-mkconfig` search for other installed systems and automatically add them to the menu, install the `os-prober` package and mount the partitions that contain the other systems. Then re-run `grub-mkconfig`.

Note for windows:

> **MS Windows**

> Often, partitions containing Windows will be automatically discovered by `os-prober`. However, NTFS partitions may not always be detected when mounted with the default Linux drivers. If GRUB is not detecting it, try installing [`NTFS-3G`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NTFS-3G) and remounting.

```
mount /dev/sda3 /mnt
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
umount /dev/sda3
```